# How can I render the same modal component into a list array itens in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I need to render a modal/lightbox component dynamic into a list array component, but it only renders the last modal content.

How can I turn this modal component dynamic to call it from the main component and populate it with correct data from an object array?

My List component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LightBox from './LightBox';

class ListPrice extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false };
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
        {this.props.products.map(product => {
         return(
          <div>
          <a key={product.id} onClick={this.toggleModal}>
              <h3>{product.title}</h3>
              <p>{product.description}</p>
           </a>
          <LightBox key={product.id} show={this.state.isOpen}
                    onClose={this.toggleModal}>
                    {product.modalContent}
          </LightBox>
        </div>
      );
    })}
   </div>
  );
 }
}
export default ListPrice;
```

And my LightBox component is (I removed styles to display short code here):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class LightBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if(!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LightBox.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  show: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.node
};

export default LightBox;
```

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: When you `console.log(this.props.products)` do you get what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

With `show={this.state.isOpen}` you always display all the modals - only the last one is visible as other modals are displayed behind it.

In order to fix that you must show only the selected dialog. You can store opened dialog in state with construct like `this.setState({ openedDialog: product.id })`.

Then you can query if the dialog is open by using `this.state.openedDialog === product.id`. That should do the job.

```
openModal = (id) = () => {
  this.setState({
    openedDialog: id
  });
}

closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({
    openedDialog: null
  });
}

show={this.state.openedDialog === product.id}
onClick={this.openModal(product.id)}
onClose={this.closeModal}
```

Comment: when I try to do this, I got an error telling me that id is not defined